# Many-to-many select stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How could I create a stored procedure in SQL Server to return a select from information from two different tables with the information from a bridge table?

My tables are:

**Room**

```
ID_Room
Name
Price
```

**Reservation**

```
ID_Res
Res_Check_In_Date
Res_Check_Out_Date
```

**BridgeRoomRes**

```
ID_Bridge
ID_Res
ID_Room
```

How could I create a stored procedure to show me all the rooms attached to one reservation?

Comment: Which DBMS you product are using? SQL is just a language.

Comment: you're right, sorry for that, I'm using MSSQL

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share any procedure you have written it will be more useful for anyone to assume what you looking for as output. also add some sample data or screenshot of your table data so one can assume your requirement more clearly. I guess following stuff may help you to find out what you looking for

I have assume here
Room - Room master table for you where you list all rooms
Reservation - Reservation master for your all list of reservation
BridgeRoomRes - Mapping table between Room and Reservation where you take both ids and allow multiple rooms to be booked in one reservation.

I assume you will pass reservation ID as parameter and call the same.

```
select Room.Name, Room.Price, Reservation.Res_Check_In_Date, Reservation.Res_Check_Out_Date
from Room
inner join BridgeRoomRes on BridgeRoomRes.ID_Room = Room.ID_Room
inner join Reservation n on BridgeRoomRes.ID_Res = Reservation.ID_Res
where Reservation.ID_Res = @ID_Res
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed! Sorry I didn't share my other  procedures, most of them have names in Spanish and all so I didn't want to confuse you guys

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will send the stored procedure @ID_Bridge parameter hopefully the following query will work for you:

```
select r.Name, r.Price, n.Res_Check_In_Date, n.Res_Check_Out_Date
from BridgeRoomRes b
inner join Room r on b.ID_Room = r.ID_Room
inner join Reservation n on b.ID_Res = n.ID_Res
where b.ID_Bridge = @ID_Bridge
```